# Why does the plus sign need to be at the end of the line instead of at the beginning on the next line?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, if you want an addition expression to span multiple lines, you need to put the plus sign at the end of the lines, not at the beginning. For example:

```
var a = 1
var b = 2
var c = 3

var d = a +
    b +
    c

println(d) // prints "6"

var e = a
    + b
    + c

println(e) // prints "1"
```

From what I can tell, this is because Kotlin is interpreting the second example as three separate statements, like this:

```
var e = a
+ b
+ c
```

But I haven't found any documentation indicating why `+ somevariable` by itself is a valid statement. It doesn't increment the variable, and `println(+somevariable)` prints the same value as `println(somevariable)`.

Comment: It's just because of the math unary operators (+ and -) `+3 == 3 == -(-3)`. Check `Int.unaryPlus()` and `Int.unaryMinus` in Kotlin docs.

Comment: Note that if you really want to put it on the next line (e.g. for readability) you can use the actual method `.plus(b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive the lines

```
val a = 5
+ 6
```

are parsed like two statements:

1. Define a `var` with value of expression `5`
2. Expression `+6`, with unary plus.

I had the same trouble in Scala and Groovy languages.
This happens because end of line is treated as end of statement — in Java only `;` is treated as end of statement so you can put `+` wherever you like.

Comment: I think you're right; I just don't understand why a unary plus all by itself, that isn't assigned to a variable or used in a method or returned from the method, would be a valid statement. I suppose it's just a language oddity.

Comment: You can write a `unaryPlus` function that performs a side-effect. In that case, doing just `+obj` will have an effect. Of course, the `unaryPlus` function on `Int` doesn't do this, but they won't make this special case not compile.

Comment: @marstran More importanly: if you look the HTML DSL example, you'll see that text content is added to a tag via `+"Text Goes Here"` line)